# Angular: why my OutPut() decorator does not raise the event from nested component to container component?

Tags: angular, events

I am learning Angular from scratch. Very beginner in this subject and please forgive me if the question is basic. 
I am learning how nested component sends data to container component by raising events using Output() decorator.
Start component is a nested component inside a a container component called product list component.
When user click on any rating star, the title of the container component should change.
But it seems that the event is not raised from star component (nested component) to the product list component (container component).
Here is my code:

star.component.html:

```
<div class="crop" 
[style.width.px]="starWidth"
[title]="rating"
(click)="onClick()">
<div style="width: 86px" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</div>
```

star.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from "@angular/core";


@Component({
    selector: 'pm-start',
    templateUrl: './star.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./star.component.css']
})

export class StarComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() rating: number;
    starWidth : number;    
    @Output() ratingClicked: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>(); 

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.starWidth = this.rating * 86/5;
    }


    onClick():void{
        console.log("stars are clicked");
        this.ratingClicked.emit(`The rating ${this.rating} was clicked`);
    }
}
```

product_list.component.html

```
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        {{pageTitle}}
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='cpl-md-2'>Filter by:</div>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = 'listFilter' />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <h3> Filter By: {{listFilter}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='table-responsive'>
            <table class='table' *ngIf='products && products.length'>
                <thead>
                    <tr class="firstRow">
                        <th>
                            <button class='btn btn-primary'
                            (click) = 'toggleImage()'>
                                {{imageShow ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}}  Image
                            </button>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Code
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Available
                        </th>
                        <th>
                             Price
                        </th>
                        <th>
                         5 Start Rating
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor='let product of filteredProducts'>
                                <td><img
                                    *ngIf = 'imageShow'
                                    [src]='product.imageUrl' [title]='product.productName' 
                                    [style.width.px] = 'imageWith' [style.height.px] = 'imageHeight'></td>
                                <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
                                <td>{{product.productCode | lowercase | covertToSpaces:'-'}}</td>                        
                                <td>{{product.releaseDate}}</td>
                                <td>{{product.price | currency:'USD': true :'1.2-2'}}</td>
                                <td><pm-start [rating]='product.starRating' (ratingClikced)='onRatingClicked($event)'></pm-start></td>
                            </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

product_list.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core"
import { IProduct } from "./product";


@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',    
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./product-list.component.css'],

})

export class ProductListComponent{
    pageTitle: string = 'Product List' ;
    imageWith: number = 40;
    imageHeight: number = 40;
    imageShow : boolean = false;
    _listFilter : string ;
    get listFilter():string {
        return this._listFilter;
    }
    set listFilter(value:string) {
        this._listFilter = value;
        this.filteredProducts = this._listFilter ? this.performFilter (this._listFilter) : this.products;
    }

    filteredProducts :IProduct[];
    products: IProduct[] = [
        {
            "productId": 1,
            "productName": "Leaf Rake",
            "productCode": "GDN-0011",
            "releaseDate": "March 19, 2016",
            "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
            "price": 19.95,
            "starRating": 3.2,
            "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/26215/Anonymous_Leaf_Rake.png"
        },
        {
            "productId": 2,
            "productName": "Garden Cart",
            "productCode": "GDN-0023",
            "releaseDate": "March 18, 2016",
            "description": "15 gallon capacity rolling garden cart",
            "price": 32.99,
            "starRating": 4.2,
            "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/58471/garden_cart.png"
        }
    ];

    constructor(){
        this.filteredProducts = this.products;
        this._listFilter = 'cart'; 
    }

    onRatingClicked(someValue:string):void{
        console.log("some body passed data form");
        this.pageTitle = "Product List " + someValue;
    }

    toggleImage ():void{
        this.imageShow = !this.imageShow; 
    };

    performFilter (filter:string){
        //
        filter = filter.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return (this.products.filter((product:IProduct) => product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1));
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a typo in your produc_list.component.html: `ratingClikced`

Comment: thanks, so ashamed of this silly mistake :( Good eyes Dude. Many thanks

Comment: We've all been there mate ;)

Comment: i am facing same problem, and unable to solve , i checked mine code there is no typo error.